# Javascript - datepicker not sending new values on change

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I am using [this datepicker](http://foundation-datepicker.peterbeno.com/example.html#docs) on my page, where I have fields to and from, and I am trying to send new value of datepicker fields on each change on them with an ajax call to server. But in console, I see that I am sending the default value which is time now, each time.

This is my script:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  //datepicker
  var date = new Date();
  var date = date.toDateString();
  $('#datePicker, #datePicker1').fdatepicker({
        closeButton: false,
    initialDate: date,
        format: 'dd.mm.yyyy',
    }).on('changeDate', function (ev) {
    timelines();
  });

  var dateFrom = $("#datePicker").val().split(".").reverse().join("-");
  var dateTo = $("#datePicker1").val().split(".").reverse().join("-");

  //timeline charts
  $("#timelines").on("change", function() {
    timelines();
  }).trigger("change");

  function timelines(){

   //get the value of selected chart option and send data to the server
   var value = $("#timelines").find(":selected").val();
   $.post("http://myapp.app/admin/statistics/timelines", {
       '_token' : $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content'),
       'option': value,
       'from': dateFrom,
       'to': dateTo,
     },
     function(data, status){
       console.log("Data: " + data + "\nStatus: " + status);
       categories = Array();
       views = Array();
       var cleanData = $.parseJSON(data);
       $.each(cleanData, function(key, value) {
         categories.push(value.time);
         views.push(value.count);
       });

       //create a chart
       $('#lineCharts').highcharts({
         chart: {
           plotBackgroundColor: null,
           plotBorderWidth: 0,
           plotShadow: false,
           backgroundColor: '#2A2E34'
         },
         credits: {
           enabled: false
         },
         exporting: {
               enabled: false
         },
         xAxis: {
             categories: categories
         },
         yAxis: {
             title: {
                 text: false
             },
             plotLines: [{
                 value: 0,
                 width: 1,
                 color: '#808080'
             }]
         },
         legend: {
             layout: 'vertical',
             align: 'right',
             verticalAlign: 'middle',
             borderWidth: 0
         },
         series: [{
             name: 'Views',
             data: views
         }]
     });
   });
  }

});
```

Updated code:

```
//datepicker
  var date = new Date();
  var date = date.toDateString();
  $('#datePicker, #datePicker1').fdatepicker({
        closeButton: false,
    initialDate: date,
        format: 'dd.mm.yyyy',
    }).on('changeDate', function (ev) {
    var dateFrom = $("#datePicker").val().split(".").reverse().join("-");
    var dateTo = $("#datePicker1").val().split(".").reverse().join("-");
    timelines(dateFrom, dateTo);
    barCharts(dateFrom, dateTo);
  });


  //timeline charts
  $("#timelines").on("change", function() {
    timelines();
  }).trigger("change");

  function timelines(dateFrom, dateTo){

   //get the value of selected chart option and send data to the server
   var value = $("#timelines").find(":selected").val();
   $.post("http://myapp.app/admin/statistics/timelines", {
       '_token' : $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content'),
       'option': value,
       'from': dateFrom,
       'to': dateTo,
     },
   //rest of the code...
```

When I do it like that if I do `console.log("From: " + dateFrom + "\ To: " + dateTo);` I get: `From: undefined To: undefined` .

Comment: which one is being set to now in the post? 'from' or 'to' or both?

Comment: Both are being sent as you can see here in the code:  'from': dateFrom,
       'to': dateTo,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are setting `dateFrom` and `dateTo` before the call is made to timelines().  At that time they are both set to the default datepicker date which is `now`.

It would be cleaner code if you passed in the things you need as an argument to `timelines()`. For example:

```
function timelines(dateFrom, dateTo){

   //get the value of selected chart option and send data to the server
   var value = $("#timelines").find(":selected").val();
   $.post("http://myapp.app/admin/statistics/timelines", {
       '_token' : $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content'),
       'option': value,
       'from': dateFrom,
       'to': dateTo,
     },
     function(data, status){
       console.log("Data: " + data + "\nStatus: " + status);
       categories = Array();
       views = Array();
       var cleanData = $.parseJSON(data);
       $.each(cleanData, function(key, value) {
         categories.push(value.time);
         views.push(value.count);
       });

       //everything else...
     });
   });
  }

});
```

The question is, how do you get dateTo and dateFrom at the time of the call to timelines?  You can use the date from the event like this: `ev.date.valueOf()` and pass that into your call to `timelines()`.

Comment: I have updated question with code as I understood you suggested, but I get an error of undefined

Comment: can you be more clear about what is undefined?  maybe drop a few console.log() 's in there to see what is undefined and where?

Comment: I have updated the question again, if anything is still unclear, let me know

Comment: where is the console.log() that is showing those errors?

I see that you're making a call to timelines() without passing in dates on the #timelines 'change'. That is probably where the dates are undefined.

Comment: I was doing console.log right above post funciton:   console.log("From: " + dateFrom + "\ To: " + dateTo);
   $.post("http://myapp.app/admin/statistics/timelines",

Comment: $("#timelines").on("change", function() {
    timelines();
  }).trigger("change");

Comment: ^ that is your problem.  You're calling timelines() without any arguments there.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/112523/discussion-between-daniel-patrick-and-marco).